# How can I modify my code to return a custom JSON instead of just status 200?

Tags: json, rest, haskell

I am trying to figure out how to implement basic auth with haskell/yesod and this is a basic implementation which works, referenced from similar questions.

```
module Handler.BasicAuth where

import Import
import Network.Wai 
import Network.HTTP.Types as Import
    ( status200 )

httpBasicAuth :: Handler ()
{-getBasicAuthR = error "Not yet implemented: getBasicAuthR"-}
httpBasicAuth = do
    request <- waiRequest
    case lookup "Authorization" (requestHeaders request) of 
        Just "Basic base64encodedusernameandpassword" -> return ()
        _ -> do
            addHeader "WWW-Authenticate" "Basic Realm=\"My Realm\""
            permissionDenied "Authentication required"

getBasicAuthR :: Handler ()
getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >>
    sendResponseStatus status200 ()
```

I would like to modify my implementation to return not just http response code 200, but also a custom JSON that reads `{"hello": "world"}`.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

As suggested by various people below, I should write `getBasicAuthR` as

```
getBasicAuthR :: Handler Value
getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse $ object ["hello" .= "world"]
```

But this just gives me an error that says

```
Handler/BasicAuth.hs:27:17:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Value -> Handler Value’
                with actual type ‘HandlerT App IO b0’
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type ‘HandlerT App IO b0’ has none
    In the expression:
      httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse $ object ["hello" .= "world"]
    In an equation for ‘getBasicAuthR’:
        getBasicAuthR
          = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse $ object ["hello" .= "world"]

Handler/BasicAuth.hs:27:34:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerT App IO b0’
                with actual type ‘c0 -> m0 a0’
    Probable cause: ‘sendResponse’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘sendResponse’
    In the expression: httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be as easy as `getBasicAuthR :: Handler JSON; getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse (object ["hello" .= "world])`?

Comment: @Zeta Yup, it should. And you can also just use `return (object ...)`, though the type of your handler would then be `Handler Value`.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: I wasn't sure, since the [documentation of `yesod-core` doesn't work on Hackage currently](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core). Is there some alternative?

Comment: Yes, http://www.stackage.org/package/yesod-core. I'm in the process of updating all of my package's to point there.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSnoyman any suggestion what I might be missing with my `sendResponse` error?

Comment: Yes, it's an operator precedence issue. Try using `(object ...)` instead of `$ object [...]`. Or use `do`-notation instead. Either should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want respond with a JSON object, you would change the type of your handler. Since `yesod-core` uses `aeson`, the appropriate type is `Handler Value`:

```
getBasicAuthR :: Handler Value
```

Due to the monad laws, `httpBasicAuth >>` stays, but is followed by `sendResponse` (or `sendResponseStatus 200`) with an additional object:

```
getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse (object ["hello" .= "world"])
```

Comment: Where do I import `JSON`?  I can't seem to find the package for it.

Comment: @CalvinCheng: Sorry, I've mistaken it with `Value`.

Comment: `getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse $ object ["hello" .= "world"]` gives an error that says `Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerT App IO b0’
                with actual type ‘c0 -> m0 a0’
    Probable cause: ‘sendResponse’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘sendResponse’
    In the expression: httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse%`

Comment: @CalvinCheng: Sorry, I didn't have much time yesterday and didn't want to provide a wrong answer, therefore I deleted it. The precedence error was already cleared up by Michael, so I changed my answer to a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from Zeta's comment:

```
getBasicAuthR :: Handler JSON
getBasicAuthR = httpBasicAuth >> sendResponse (object ["hello" .= "world])
```